# Websocket connection to 'wss://url' failed : [vite] server connnection lost. polling for restart... after deploying the vitejs project in AWS EC2

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, firebase, npm, vite

I have created the vite project it is working perfectly fine in the localhost. But when my project was deployed in AWS EC2 instance, I am getting following error message :

```
Websocket connection to 'wss://www.domain.com/3000' failed:
[vite] server connnection lost. polling for restart...
```

pacakge.json :

```
{
"name": "screen-recording-demo",
"version": "0.0.0",
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "serve": "vite preview"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "vite": "^2.0.5"
},
"dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^8.2.10"
}
}
```

I have used firebase dependencies in my project in locally everything is working fine. I have checked the [vite doumentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html), but not getting what needs to be added or I am missing in the production.

Comment: Hello. Didn't find the answer to this question? And then I also faced this problem

Answer (score 1):

based on my experience this a day ago, i need to open the port used

in Nuxt 3 it's 24678, so i must execute these

`ufw allow 24678/tcp`